# Topshelf.Fsharp install command does nothing

Tags: f#, windows-services, topshelf

I am trying to create a Windows service in F# using Topshelf. I have taken the sample code from the [Github readme](https://github.com/haf/Topshelf.FSharp/blob/master/src/Topshelf.FSharp.Example/Program.fs)

When I try to run the command line (as an Administrator)

```
MyService.exe install -serviceName:MyWindowsService
MyService.exe start
```

nothing happens. There is no error but no service appears in the Services dialog. I do see an entry in the System Event viewer saying "A service was installed on the system", but I don't see any sign of it.

Can anyone think of anything I have missed?

Answer (score 4):

For anyone interested, I had created my project as a Windows Application. Changing it to a console application fixed the problem.